# Data frames from dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Currently I have a large set of code that creates a dictionary. I need this dictionary to be a DataFrame. Currently I have def get_tasks(), which returns a dictionary. Is there anyway to create a df from this function since it returns the the dictionary?

Comment: Could you edit your question and include a snippet of how the dictionary looks? That might help people help you quicker :)

Comment: I think this is the method for it: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: What does the dict look like? Can you share it here? There are many ways to create a df from dict